# safari not showing save dialog box

Tags: php, magento, safari

I am working with a magento website. I have .dxf , .pdf files in a folder on my website. When I try to download .dxf file from website will download correctly but directly open browser window. I have hyperlinks/anchor tags that allow you to download these files by clicking on the link, and you get the normal dialogue that asks you to download. It works for PDF and DWG but not for DXF. how to show save dialogue box in safari for dxf file.

I tried following code:

```
  <div class="pdf-text">
     <a target="_blank" href="/pdf/test.dxf" download="/pdf/test.dxf">CAD Drawing Template</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code in .htaccess file

AddType application/octet-stream .dxf